# Where to get OpenCL SDK?

Tags: sdk, opencl, intel, amd-gpu, amd-rocm

I tried to download OpenCL SDK. But no way. I have an AMD GPU so I searched on Google for AMD SDK but all the links from Google and some tutorials are broken and there is no possibility to find the SDK through the AMD developers site.

Well I tried then Intel OpenCL SDK but there is no direct link. I tried to register and apply for the SDK but I don't see any download links in my mail box.

Is it that difficult to get your hands on OpenCL SDKs? Something I am missing?

**Update:**

Finally as for OpenGL SDK is only needed for headers and libs. And tools.

Looks like the SDK is deprecated and we should just use OpenCL SDK Lite that only contains headers and library files:
https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases Pretty disappointing.

There are still tools related to ROCm for linux but not much for Windows. CodeXL should work on Windows though.

For Intel SDK I finally received a confirmation mail and could download it. It took a couple of days.

Comment: Intel OpenCL CPU runtime can be downloaded directly from: https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers

Comment: Yep I've seen that but I'm searching for *.libd that should be included in the SDK. Finally I've received the mail from Intel with teh link. It's unfortunate that registration with a long validation is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full Installers:

32-bit: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/app-sdk/installers/APPSDKInstaller/3.0.130.135-GA/full/AMD-APP-SDKInstaller-v3.0.130.135-GA-windows-F-x86.exe

64-bit: http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/app-sdk/installers/APPSDKInstaller/3.0.130.135-GA/full/AMD-APP-SDKInstaller-v3.0.130.135-GA-windows-F-x64.exe

Comment: Looks like the SDK is deprecated and we should just use OpenCL SDK Lite that only contains headers and library files: https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/OCL-SDK/releases Pretty disappointing. There are still tools related to ROCm for linux but not much for Windows. CodeXL should work on windows thow.

Answer (score 1):

On Win64, you can build the SDK yourself. Get the OpenCL headers from Khronos, and build the import library from the OpenCL.dll using the VC++ tools. See [csidev.net](http://csidev.net).